# Altering css properties using jQuery within an if statement

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I have made some menus which have items that expand when the user clicks on them. Whenever the menu item is expanded, the headline of the item is supposed to change style using .css()

Since the menus are styled differently, there is an if statement within the script, that checks whether the user clicked a menu2 or a menu3 item to apply the appropriate style when it expands.

EDIT: The problem is that the styling changes do not apply as they should.

I replaced $this to $(this) as Sushanth suggested, but the problem persists, check the example (updated)

Code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".toggle-trigger").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().nextAll('.toggle-wrap').first().slideToggle('slow','swing'); 


      if( $(this).is("menu2 .headline a")) {
            $(this).toggle(
                function(){
                $(this).parent().css("background-color","rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",'border', 'solid 2px #009e0f');
                $(this).css("color","#009e0f");
                },
                function(){
                $(this).parent().css("background-color","#009e0f","border",'solid 2px #009e0f');
                $(this).css("color","#ffffff");
                }
            );
        }

        else if( $(this).is("#menu3 .headline a")) {
            $(this).toggle(
                function(){
                $(this).parent().css("background-color","rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",'border', 'solid 2px #f7b50c');
                $(this).css("color","#f7b50c");
                },
                function(){
                $(this).parent().css("background-color","#009e0f","border",'solid 2px #f7b50c');
                $(this).css("color","#ffffff");
                }
            );
        }



    });
});
```

});

Comment: That's great, but do you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this
```

supposed to be    **//**  `In the if statements if( $this.is("menu2 .headline a"))`

```
$(this)
```

Or **cache** `var $this = $(this)`

**UPDATE**

I see two more problem with the code ...

- Missing # sign in this line `if( $(this).is("#menu2 .headline a"))`
  Second problem is in the way you are assigning the **CSS properties.**.

  .css("background-color","#009e0f","border",'solid 2px #f7b50c')

You have multiple properties .. So the properties are supposed to be in the form of `a map` with **key:value pairs..**

```
.css({
       "background-color": "#009e0f",
       "border": 'solid 2px #f7b50c'
 });
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/GeHBD/1/)**

No need to encase your code in both `$(window).load()` and `DOM Ready handler`.. One is sufficient.
Also there seems to be a problem with the **toggling**

**UPDATE**

Optimized without using toggle

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle-trigger").click(function() {
        // cache the div next to anchor
        var $div = $(this).parent().nextAll('.toggle-wrap').first();
        $div.slideToggle('slow', 'swing');
        // cache $(this)
        var $this = $(this);
        var background = '';
        var color = '';
        // Checking id the div has no class called hidden
        if (!$div.hasClass('hidden')) {
            // then add the class to the div
            $div.addClass('hidden');
            background = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)";
            // closest ancestor of the link cliked is menu2
            if ($this.closest('#menu2').length) {
                color = "#009e0f";
            }
            // closest ancestor of the link cliked is menu2
            else if ($this.closest('#menu3').length) {
                color = "#f7b50c";
            }
        }
        // if the div has a class hidden then 
        else {
            // Remove the hidden class
            $div.removeClass('hidden');
            color = "#ffffff";
            if ($this.closest('#menu2').length) {
                background = "#009e0f";
            }
            else if ($this.closest('#menu3').length) {
                background = "#f7b50c";
            }
        }
        // set the background  and color based on conditions
        $this.parent().css("background-color" , background );
        $this.css("color" , color);
    });
});​
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/GeHBD/3/)**

Comment: Dis you check this line if( $(this).is("menu2 .headline a"))  Missing #sign..  if( $(this).is("#menu2 .headline a"))

Comment: I added the missing hashtag, and updated the example files, but now the problem is that the style changes after you click on the item for the second time, and just stays this way... 
So i'm guessing that i've messed up somewhere in the toggle part... still no clue how/where but check the example to see for yourself the weird behavior.

Comment: Thanx for addressing the CSS properties assignment issue, but the problem still persists even after the change. :/
Any ideas what could be wrong in the way I'm using toggle?

Comment: You don't need to use toggle in the first Place.. I have optimized part of your code.. Check it .. Let me know if you have any questions..http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/GeHBD/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the implementation, but could you explain a bit the logic behind this code? I'm too new into jQuery to fully grasp it. I was trying to figure a way on how i could expand all the items of a clicked menu at once when the user clicked the "Menu 2" or "Menu 3", but couldn't understand how I'd be able to do it. Any pointers there? Thank you again!